# Summarize the result of the table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL.
I have the data in table like:

```
Parent_id     Count     Read
---------     ------    ------
52405          2         False
52405          1         True
```

Now i want to summarize the data  like :

```
Parent_id     Count     Read
---------     ------    ------
52405          3         False
```

`Count` would be the **sum** of the records.
`Read` would be the logical **AND** operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    "Parent_id",
    SUM("Count"),
    bool_and("Read")
FROM
    tablename
GROUP BY
    "Parent_id";
```

I did use double quotes " because of illegal column names and the use of upper case in the names.

Comment: which DBMS'es support it? never heard of it and google doesn't help.

Comment: PostgreSQL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html And now I see this topic is tagged for other dbms's as well...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Parent_id,
       s,
       CASE WHEN logical_sum = cnt
            THEN 'True'
            ELSE 'False'
       END
  FROM (SELECT SUM("Count") as s,
               SUM(CASE WHEN "Read" = 'True'
                        THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                   END) AS logical_sum,
               COUNT(*) AS cnt
          FROM tbl
      GROUP BY Parent_id) x
```